# function-pointers and class-templates

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

I have a template class CFoo using the following types

```
enum My_Types {t1,t2};
```

with the specialization given by

```
template<My_Types T>
class CFoo
{
    public:
    CFoo()
    {
        std::cerr<<"ERROR:....";
        exit(1);
    }
};

template<>
class CFoo<t1>
{
    ....
};
```

In addition I have a function which uses a CFoo object as an argument

```
template<class T>
void foo1 ( const T &CfooObj,...);
```

Now I need a pointer to foo1, so I have to specify the template argument

```
void (*foo1_pointer) ( const CFoo< t1 >&,...);
```

But the following seems not to be correct (" no matches converting function foo1..."):

```
foo1_pointer=&foo1;
```

How to pass the pointer of this template function correctly?

Comment: [Compiles fine for me](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4cboZz$0)

Comment: What is your compiler btw?

Comment: @AndyProwl: c++ (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1) 4.4.3

Comment: @pawel_winzig: I asked what *compiler*, not OS. GCC, Clang, ...?

Comment: @AndyProwl: sorry, typo: gcc

Comment: @pawel_winzig: OK, you might consider upgrading to a newer version then. The code should compile (see my answer for an explanation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably due to the old version of your GCC compiler. This code compiles fine on GCC 4.7.2, Clang 3.2, ICC 13.0.1, and VS10:

```
#include <iostream>

enum My_Types {t1,t2};

template<My_Types T>
class CFoo { /* ... */ };

template<> class CFoo<t1> { /* ... */ };

template<class T>
void foo1 (const T &, ...) { /* ... */ }

int main()
{
    void (*foo1_pointer) (const CFoo< t1 >&, ...);
    foo1_pointer = &foo1;
}
```

The compiler should be able to deduce the template arguments of `foo1` when taking its address from the type of the function pointer it is assigned to. Per Paragraph 14.8.2.3/1 of the C++11 Standard:

> Template arguments can be deduced from the type specified when taking the address of an overloaded function (13.4). The function template’s function type and the specified type are used as the types of P and A, and the deduction is done as described in 14.8.2.5.

And also, per Paragraph 13.4/1:

> A use of an overloaded function name without arguments is resolved in certain contexts to a function, a pointer to function or a pointer to member function for a specific function from the overload set. *A function template name is considered to name a set of overloaded functions in such contexts. The function selected is the one whose type is identical to the function type of the target type required in the context.* [...]

Answer (score 0):

You can just write `foo1<CFoo<t1>>`. Or just `foo1` (works with g++ 4.7.2).

Answer (score 0):

The assignment should be like this:

```
foo1_pointer = &foo1<CFoo<t1>>;
```